# TableLayout in Android

Tags: android, layout, tableview

I have several distinct `View` objects, stored in the `views` array, that I want to show together on the screen. Therefore, as far as I understand it correctly, a `TableView` would do exactly that. However, I can only see one of the views, i.e. like there is a single row, not to rows. Here goes my code:

```
class myApp extends Activity {

    FrameLayout mainFrame = ...;
    View[] views = ...;

    ...

    TableLayout grid = new TableLayout(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.addView(views[i]);
        grid.addView(row);//, i);
    }

    mainFrame.addView(grid, 1);
```

### UPDATE

Turns out the previous code actually *didn't show anything*.

I can see something only if I don't use `TableRow`, but then I'd get one row only, i.e.:

```
class myApp extends Activity {

    FrameLayout mainFrame = ...;
    View[] views = ...;

    ...

    TableLayout grid = new TableLayout(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
        grid.addView(views[i]);
    }

    mainFrame.addView(grid, 1);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
grid.setOrientation(TableLayout.VERTICAL)
```

Comment: Very strange. Actually there's no need to use TableView here, because for displaying the list of views you may also use LinearLayout or ListView, like shown here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html . The TableView should consist of TableRows, which also have their orientation (try specifying it as well). After you set orientation you may add array view to the rows but it's too complicated. As I said LinearLayout or ListView are ok for your purpose ( if I got it right )

Comment: Thanks! Well, adding views to the `ListView` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Funny, indeed!

Comment: Yep, that is because ListView does not support addView() function. You could use this tutorial: http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf . In general you will have to create xml describing list cell and then create adapter to make it work. Even though using listView is comfortable when you have similar views. When the views are completely different, you should use LinearLayout.